# Primitive cell and primitive vectors

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

In Ashcroft's *"Solid state physics"* it's said that

> The obvious cell to associate with a particular set of primitive vectors, $\textbf a_1$,$\textbf a_2$,$\textbf a_1$, is a set of all points $r$ of the form : $\textbf r=x_1\textbf a_1+x_2\textbf a_2+x_3 \textbf a_3$, for all $x_i$ ranging continuously between 0 and 1.

**My question:** I understand what a primitive cell is, I just don't understand why it can always be chosen so that it is spanned by the primitve vectors. Why can't I choose the primitve vectors so that they'll never span a primitive cell? Is there a (relatively) simple proof for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primitive cell is defined as being the cell constructed from primitive vectors, not the other way around.

You first find three vectors (between each lattice site) which encode the translational invariance of your lattice, then use these to construct the primitive cell. If this cell is not the smallest possible cell (by volume), then it is a unit cell only, the primitive cell being the smallest possible unit cell.

Comment: In my book it says: " A volume of space that, when translated through all the vectors in the Bravais lattice, just fills all of space without either overlapping itself or leaving voids is called a primitve cell", so this is equivalent to the definition you stated:  "The primitive cell is defined as being the cell constructed from primitive vectors, not the other way around. " ??

Comment: Yes that would be equivalent. Essentially the primitive cell is used to construct the entire lattice, by copying the cell n times and translating it along any primitive vector.