# Are there primitive unit cells which cannot be associated with primitive vectors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, lattice-model

In the theory of Bravais lattices, it is immediate to associate with each set of primitive unit vectors a primitive unit cell (see e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315414/primitive-cell-and-primitive-vectors)). It is (probably) not hard to show that this map is an injection from the set of sets of primitive vectors to the set of primitive unit cells. But is this a surjection, or does there exist some other map which is a bijection? Equivalently, are there primitive unit cells which do not "correspond" to some primitive unit vectors?

I would have guessed that something like the Wigner-Seitz cell supplies such an example, but I can't figure out how to prove that it can't be generated by some primitive vectors.

Edit: Perhaps I should also ask for confirmation that every set of primitive vectors does indeed imply a given primitive unit cell.

Comment: First off, the primitive unit vectors should be considered up to a sign and reordering for the correspondence to have a chance of being one to one. Furthermore, it depends on your definition of primitive unit cell. If you assume that it’s a parallelepiped, then yes by taking the extremal points. However, you are typically interested in WS cells which exhibit the symmetry of lattice. There will therefore be many corresponding primitive vector basis associated to a single cell. Take for example the the hexagonal lattice in 2D. Perhaps modify your question to get rid of such counterexamples.

Comment: I am using Ashcroft and Mermin’s definition that a primitive unit cell is a volume of space which fills all of space without overlapping when translated through all Bravais lattice vectors (i.e. it tiles all of space). Are you saying there are more sets of primitive vectors (yes, up to minus signs and reordering) than cells? I can’t think of what the primitive vectors would be for arbitrary WS cells? @LPZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easily seen that this map is not surjective, e.g. only cells that are parallelepipeds are generated.

There actually cannot exist any surjection: there are many more primitive unit cells than sets of primitive vectors (or *bases* of the lattice), the first is uncountable, the second is countable.
To see that the set of bases (triples of primitive vectors) is countable, note that every basis is related to any other by an element of $\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb Z)$, the group of invertible (equivalently determinant $\pm 1$) $3\times3$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$, so the cardinality of $\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb Z)$ is an upper bound for that of sets of primitive vectors.

On the other hand, take any primitive unit cell. You can construct a new one by translating it by any vector in $\mathbb R^3$, which already gives you uncountable many different ones.

If you don't want to consider these as different, you could cut the cell in two, in any way you like, and translate one half by a nonzero element of the lattice, giving a new cell for each way of cutting, of which there are uncountable many as well. This can be done for a partition in any number of subsets.

Comment: Does anything change if I specify that a primitive unit cell must be topologically equivalent to a sphere (no holes)? Additionally, can you comment in particular as to whether primitive vectors would exist for WS cells in arbitrary Bravais lattices?

Comment: The set of primitive cells homeomorphic to a ball would still be uncountable, even if you prohibit translations (e.g. by requiring that it contain the origin). You could start out with a parallelepiped generated by $a_1, a_2, a_3$, cut off a blob of an appropriate shape adjacent to the face generated by $a_1$ and $a_2$ and move it along $a_3$ for example

Comment: As for the other question, what constitutes a primitive vector is independent of any choice of cell, it only depends on the lattice, so I'll take your question on WS cells as meaning if there is an algorithm to give you a set of primitive vectors from a (single) WS cell. Probably you can do something like this: the faces of the cell are polygons which come in pairwise parallel congruent pairs (on opposite sides of the cell). The vectors translating them into each other should contain a set of primitive vectors (and their inverses), but will generally contain more elements.

Comment: Some arguments went above my head but I really appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: You're welcome!